# Is HD7670 4GB DDR5 128 Bit compatible with Blender

Tags: rendering, gpu, compatibility

```
     Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 18362) (18362.19h1_release.190318-1202)
             Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
  System Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
         System Model: OptiPlex 390
                 BIOS: Default System BIOS (type: BIOS)
            Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.1GHz
               Memory: 8192MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 8090MB RAM
            Page File: 5779MB used, 4229MB available
          Windows Dir: C:\Windows
      DirectX Version: DirectX 12
  DX Setup Parameters: Not found
```

I'm using blender V2.79, running windows 10, please view the specs for more details. I'm about to buy this card from a friend HD7670 4GB DDR5 128 Bit. I want to know if it's compatible with my Blender version on workstation?

Answer (score 1):

The AMD Radeon HD 7670 is from the [Radeon HD 7000 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Radeon_7000_series) and has the TeraScale 2 architecture.

---

**Blender 2.79**:

The [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for AMD GPUs, in order to run Blender, are:

> Blender 2.79 runs on all systems that support OpenGL 2.1 and above, with recent graphics drivers. For macOS, version 10.9 and later are supported.

The [minimum requirements for GPU rendering with OpenCL](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html?highlight=gpu#opencl) are:

> **OpenCL**
>
> OpenCL is supported for GPU rendering with AMD graphics cards. (We only support graphics cards with GCN architecture 2.0 and above). To make sure your GPU is supported checkout [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units).

**Conclusion for Blender 2.79:**

It would be possible to run Blender 2.79 with the AMD Radeon HD 7670 graphics card, however you already have an integrated GPU in the Intel i5-2400 that satisfies this requirement as well. The AMD Radeon HD 7670 does not meet the requirements for GPU rendering.

---

**Blender 2.8x**:

The [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for AMD GPUs, in order to run Blender, are:

> **AMD**: GCN 1st gen and newer

The [minimum requirements for GPU rendering with OpenCL](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#amd) are:

> **AMD**
>
> OpenCL is supported for GPU rendering with AMD graphics cards. Blender supports graphics cards with GCN generation 2 and above. To make sure your GPU is supported, see the [list of GCN generations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Core_Next#Iterations) with the GCN generation and supported graphics cards.
>
> AMD OpenCL GPU rendering is supported on Windows and Linux, but not on macOS.

**Conclusion for Blender 2.8x:**

The AMD Radeon HD 7670 graphics card is not supported for Blender 2.8x.

---

I wouldn't recommend buying the AMD Radeon HD 7670.